# DBpedia Spotlight, SPARQL filter missing entires

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, spotlight-dbpedia

I have trouble with the sparql option in DBpedia spotlight. My result set looks like this without a sparql filter:

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Starting_lineup
http://dbpedia.org/resource/One_Week_%28song%29
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Longitude
http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Fly_%281986_film%29
http://dbpedia.org/resource/San_Francisco_International_Airport
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cycling
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Golden_Gate_Bridge
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sausalito,_California
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lunch
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ferry
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Angel_Island_%28California%29
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cycling
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Twin_Peaks
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richmond_Park
http://dbpedia.org/resource/China_Beach
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Minas_Gerais
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jazz
```

Several of these entities have the property `rdf:type` `dbpedia-owl:Place`. But when I filter with the following sparql query:

```
" PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> "+
" PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> " +
" PREFIX dbpedia_ont: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> " +
" SELECT DISTINCT ?x WHERE { ?x rdf:type dbpedia_ont:Place . }";
```

I only get two results:

- `http://dbpedia.org/resource/San_Francisco_International_Airport`
- `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Minas_Gerais`

Where are the others:

- `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Golden_Gate_Bridge`
- `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sausalito,_California`
- `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richmond_Park`

etc.?

Comment: I think this isn't the exact query that you're running.  If you take that query over to the public endpoint, it returns lots of results.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something you're not showing us.  When I run  your query (with a `limit 100`) on the [DBpedia public SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), I get lots of results:

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbpedia_ont: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?x WHERE { ?x rdf:type dbpedia_ont:Place . }
limit 100
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20geo%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdf%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpedia_ont%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20?x%20WHERE%20%7B%20?x%20rdf%3atype%20dbpedia_ont%3aPlace%20.%20%7D%0D%0Alimit%20100&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

*Note:  I'd also suggest that, when possible, you use the same prefixes that DBpedia already defines for its endpoint.  E.g., use `dbpedia-owl:` for `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/`, not `dbpedia_ont`.  This will make it **much** easier for other people to copy and paste your queries to try them out.*

Comment: I am including the sparql query as a filter option to the DBpedia Spotlight API

Comment: @user2498899 I think you'll need to include your code to execute the query then.  Your query works just fine on the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint.  Please include code that we can test.